# Server to Server events in Socket.io

Tags: redis, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I'm using [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) with [Redis Adapter](https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/) in GKE where I have two replicas of socket server I want to create something scale able that's why I'm using redis pub/sub but I also need to listen when something happen in other replica,  is it possible to send events from one replica to another replica.

**Server1.js**

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { createAdapter } from "@socket.io/redis-adapter";
import { createClient } from "redis";

const io = new Server();

const pubClient = createClient({ url: "redis://localhost:6379" });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
io.listen(3000);

io.on("custom-event", () => {
console.log("Custom event occur");
});
```

**From replica** I want to fire event

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { createAdapter } from "@socket.io/redis-adapter";
import { createClient } from "redis";

const io = new Server();

const pubClient = createClient({ url: "redis://localhost:6379" });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
io.listen(3000);

io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.emit("custom-event"); // not working
    io.emit("custom event") // not working
})
```

How is it possible or is there any alternative.

Comment: If each server had a `socket.io-client` connected to themselves and that client io instance handled `custom event` this would work.  I'm not sure if that's a reliable way to do IPC but it would work.